# How to set navigation bar font colour and size

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I have been trying to set both the font size and the font colour of the text in my navigation bar, however I have been having issues.

Basically what seems to be happening is my two lines of code overwrite each other and I can only get them to work on their own.

Here is my code:

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 30)]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

What do I need to change so that I can change the font size and colour?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In swift Mandav's excellent answer could be implemented this way:

```
var attributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.greenColor(),
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 30)!
]
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes
```

Note that the `UIFont` initializer returns an optional because it could fail to find the font, so an exclamation point is used.

Comment: ahem, have you noticed the date of the answer?

Comment: Perfect!! worked on 9.2 like a charm :) happy to upvote

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread but I needed answer for Objective-c. I found out how to do this. Let me post it here in case other programmer runs into the same problem. For objective-c you can achieve that by setting attributes in NSDictionary like this.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor]                                                ,NSForegroundColorAttributeName,                                                       [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:30]                                                       , NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
```